# How to simply walk through directories and subdirectories and create archive if found certain files

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, tar

I would like to create 2 scripts. First would be responsible for traversing through all subdirectories in parent folder, looking for files with extension `"*.mp4", "*.txt","*.jpg"` and if folder (for example `testfolder`) with such three files is found, another scripts performs operation of creating archive `testfolder.tar`.

Here is my directory tree for testing those scripts:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nplWD.jpg

`rootDirectory` contains `parentDirectory1` and `parentDirectory2`. `parentDirectories` contain `childDirectories`.

Here is code of `dirScanner.py` trying to print extensions of files in subdirs:

```
import os

rootdir = r'C:\Users\user\pythonprogram\rootDirectory'
for directory in os.walk(rootdir):
    for subdirectory in directory:
        extensions = []
        if os.path.isfile(os.curdir):
            extensions.append(os.path.splitext(os.curdir)[-1].lower())
        print(extensions)
```

However it absolutely does not work as I expect it to work. 
How should I traverse through `parentDirectories` and `childDirectiories` in `rootDirectory`?

I would like to keep it simple, in the way "Okay I'm in this directory, the files of this directory are XXX, Should/Shouldn't pack them"

Also, this is my other script that should be responsible for packing files for specified path. I'm trying to learn how to use classes however I don't know if I understand it correctly.

```
import tarfile

class folderNeededToBePacked:
    def __init__(self, name, path):
        self.path = path
        self.name = name
    def pack(self):
        tar = tarfile.open(r"{0}/{1}.tar".format(self.path, self.name), "w")
        for file in self.path:
            tar.add(file)
        tar.close()
```

I'd be thankful for all tips and advices how to achieve the goal of this task.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.walk) gives a good example on how to use `os.walk`. Also, you say _looking for files with extension `"*.mp4", "*.txt","*.jpg"`_. Are you sure you don't mean _*.nfo_ ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple straight forward task without many complex concepts which would call for being implemented as a class, so I would not use one for this.

The idea is to walk through all directories (recursively) and if a *matching* directory is found, pack the three files of this directory into the archive.

To walk through the directory tree you need to fix your usage of 'os.walk()' according to its documentation:

```
tar = tarfile.open(...)
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
  found_files = dir_matching(root, dirpath)
  for found_file in found_files:
    tar.add(found_file)
tar.close()
```

And the function `dir_matching()` should return a list of the three found files (or an empty list if the directory doesn't match, i.e. at least one of the three necessary files is missing):

```
def dir_matching(root, dirpath):
  jpg = glob.glob(os.path.join(root, dirpath, '*.jpg')
  mp4 = glob.glob(os.path.join(root, dirpath, '*.mp4')
  txt = glob.glob(os.path.join(root, dirpath, '*.txt')
  if jpg and mp4 and txt:
    return [ jpg[0], mp4[0], txt[0] ]
  else:
    return []
```

Of course you could add more sophisticated checks e.g. whether *exactly* one jpg etc. is found, but that depends on your concrete specifications.

Comment: If you prefer to have separate tar files, one for each directory (this sounds a bit implausible but your wording could be understood like this), then opening, filling, and closing the tar file should be done in the function in case the three files have been found, and nothing needs to be returned of course.

Comment: And, yes, it can be optimized by scrutinizing the `filenames` variable instead of using the `glob` module, but this way I think it is clearer.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have separate tar archives, each tar archive should be saved in rootdir and its name should be `poster.jpg` from archived folder without extension.
Thank you for your help, however I got another problem.
I achieved the goal, folders containing specified files are archived, however when i open the archive I see the whole folder path to files, i.e. when i open `poster11.tar` I see `users/user/rootDirectory/parentDirectory1/childDirectory11` and then files.
How could I create archive just with files, without folders?

Comment: `tar.add()` can take a second argument which describes the file as part of the tar archive and in there you can truncate the path.  If this isn't enough to solve the issue, I propose to create a new question for this and then refer to this one here so you don't have to explain too much ;-)

Comment: Would you like to help me and look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60724851/scripts-traversing-through-directories-looking-for-specific-set-of-files-and-fol

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you know anything that could help me with above problem :( ?