# Scripts traversing through directories looking for specific set of files and folders

Tags: python, operating-system, tar, archive, directory-traversal

I'm trying to create a script that will traverse through all folders and subfolders of `rootDir` looking for specific set of folders and files. If script will find the folder (for ex. `testfolder1`) in which there are:

- `textfile.txt`
- `image.jpg`
- (optionally) `subtitles.dxfp`
- another folder (ex. `testsubfolder1`) containing `video.mp4` file
- (optionally) another folder (ex. `testsubfolder2`) containing `video_trailer.mp4` file

it will create archive containing `textfile.txt`, `image.jpg`, `subtitles.dxfp`(if they were in found), `video.mp4` and `video_trailer.mp4` (if it was found) and save it in rootDir.

Currently I have snippet that traverse recursively looking for all those files, but it's not including that `video.mp4` and `video_trailer.mp4` are in folders. How should I modify my code in order to achieve wanted effect?
I guess it should look at the beginning if `textfile.txt`, `image.jpg` and `subtitles.dxfp` were found, if so it looks if there exist folder containing `video.mp4` file, but not recursively and at the end it searches for another folder containing `video_trailer.mp4` file. Am i right? I do not know how should i properly write it in code.
Thank you in advance for any tips bringing me closer to the solution.

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootDir):
    jpg = glob.glob(os.path.join(rootDir, dirpath, '*.jpg'))
    mp4 = glob.glob(os.path.join(rootDir, dirpath, '*.mp4'))
    txt = glob.glob(os.path.join(rootDir, dirpath, '*.txt'))
    xml = glob.glob(os.path.join(rootDir, dirpath, '*.xml'))
    dxfp = glob.glob(os.path.join(rootDir, dirpath, '*.dxfp'))

    if jpg and mp4 and txt:
        if xml and dxfp:
            #Archive will have the same name as image
            tarName  = [i for i in filenames if ".jpg" in i] 
            tar = tarfile.open("{0}.tar".format(tarName[0].replace(".jpg","")), "w")

            for file in [jpg, mp4, txt, xml, dxfp]:
                tar.add(file[0])
            tar.close()
        else:
            tarName  = [i for i in filenames if ".jpg" in i] 
            tar = tarfile.open("{0}.tar".format(tarName[0].replace(".jpg","")), "w")
            for file in [jpg, mp4, txt]:
                tar.add(file[0])
            tar.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

what about using find?

```
find / -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec tar -czf /tmp/jpg.tar.gz {} \;
```

with -u you can update existing archives.

Greetings, fuchs

Comment: User is looking for a solution in python not the unix command which achieves it.